# Salesforce Apex Convert Leads with the same AccountId "Duplicate id in list: "

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

Is there a standard way of converting Leads with the same AccountId in Salesforce.  When trying to do it with the following code, I get the error "Duplicate id in list"

```
List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
for(Lead myLead : leadsToConvert){
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();

    if (accountMap.get(myLead.Company) <> null) {

        lc.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
        lc.setAccountId(accountMap.get(myLead.Company).id);
        lc.setOverwriteLeadSource(true);

        //if we match to a contact, merge
        if (contactMap.get(myLead.Email) != null && myLead.Email != null) {
            lc.setContactId(contactMap.get(myLead.Email).id);
        }               

        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        leadConverts.add(lc);           
    }
}

if(!leadConverts.isEmpty()){
    Database.convertLead(leadConverts, false);
}
```

This code only fails when I pass in a List of leads that have the same AccountID.  I get the "Duplicate id in list" error.

Why can I not do this?
Is there a standard practice/ way to avoid this?

Comment: Hi @louis, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Comment: Haha, I realized that right after I posted here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks correct, converting multiple leads to the same account should work just fine.

Most likely your leadsToConvert list has the same lead more than once.  You can quickly validate this by using a map to prevent duplicates.

```
List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id, Lead>(leadsToConvert);
for(Lead myLead : leadMap.values()){
```